# using NSUserDefaults to display score

Tags: ios, swift

I am using NSUserDefaults to display the score from my `GameScene` on my `resetViewController`. The problem is that if the user doesn't score it will display the players last score.

In GameScene

```
var score: Int = 0
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

score++
scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
defaults.setObject(scoreLabel.text, forKey: "scoring")
```

In resetViewController

```
var score = defaults().stringForKey("scoring")
YourScore.text = score
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Do you even need NSUserDefaults then. If you only show the current data to user and reset previous plays score, you could simply do it with some properties in your view controller or using some global variables.

Answer (score 1):

When you need to score to reset, just call

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nil, forKey: "scoring")
```

Answer (score 0):

`removeObjectForKey:` removes the value from NSUserDefaults. You could also set it to zero. Or just not use NSUserDefaults -- there's not much point in using it unless you need to persist the value between restarts of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest saving the integer, not the string. That way the default will be zero, and you can easily reset the score by setting the key to zero.

```
NSUserdefaults.standardUserDefaults().IntegerForKey("score")
NSUserdefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(0, forKey: "score")
```